# ng-src not working for image source with conditional operator

Tags: angularjs

I am using conditional operator to set source of an image. 
Image is from data base andit will be a base64 string.
I am getting one more Boolean from database whether user has set his profile photo or not.
If he sets a picture, I am setting that as source else one local svg file.
 below is my code snippet.

```
 <img id="profilePic" ng-src="{{ photoSet ? 'data:image/jpeg;base64,userPhoto': 'Images/profile.svg' }}"/>
```

but both the cases it is not working.
Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: <img id="mprofilePic" ng-src="{{photoSet ? 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + userPhoto : 'Images/profile.svg'}}"/>       this is working

Answer (score 1):

You need to use curly braces to make sure the value reaches ng-src.

You can use any of the following.

userPhoto should contain the base64 value in both the cases

```
 <img id="profilePic" ng-src="{{photoSet}} ? 'data:image/jpeg;base64,{{userPhoto}}': 'Images/profile.svg'"/>
```

OR

```
<img ng-if="photoSet" id="profilePic" ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{userPhoto}}"/>
<img ng-if="!photoSet" id="profilePic" ng-src="Images/profile.svg"/>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. The opening and closing braces are not matching in your code. This is not working also.

Comment: <img id="mprofilePic" ng-src="{{photoSet ? 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + userPhoto : 'Images/profile.svg'}}"/>      this is working

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the path in the following way and check for the conditions in `ng-if`.

```
<img  ng-if="photoSet" ng-src="1stImagePathHere" />
<img  ng-if="!photoSet" ng-src="2ndImagePathHere" />
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, This is ok but I need with conditional operator.

Comment: Please post something more than just a few lines of code. Explain your answer etc. You can read more about how to answer a question here: [answer]